# wxpython como importar acciones de boton desde otro py file

Tags: python, interfaz-gráfica, wxwidgets

Hola mi pregunta es algo extraña, pero si en wxpython he creado una ventana en el archivo main.py

```
import wx
import wx.xrc
#from accion import evento

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, title=u"Muestra", pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.Size(500, 300),
                          style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

        self.SetSizeHints(wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize)

        bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.texto = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        bSizer1.Add(self.texto, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, 5)

        self.buton = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"ejecutar", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        bSizer1.Add(self.buton, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(bSizer1)
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre(wx.BOTH)

        # Connect Events
        self.buton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.iniciar)

    def __del__(self):
        pass

    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def iniciar(self, event):
        #evento()    quiero ejecutar desde otro py
        event.Skip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

ahora creo el archivo "accion.py" pero quiero hacer que al hacer click,
éste importe los comandos de accion.py, creo que necesito de una clase **class** o un **def** que se crea en accion, por ejemplo

```
def evento(self):
    texto = self.self.texto.GetLineText(0)
    print(texto)
```

y si quiero crear por ejemplo más acciones de boton o de otros, esto es con el fin de escribir menos codigo del py padre.
Pueden ayudarme por favor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero de todo tal y como lo planteas, lo que realmente quieres es implementar una clase a lo largo de diferentes módulos, **mover un método de instancia de la definición de la clase a un módulo externo**.

Python no es un lenguaje que imponga demasiadas restricciones, te deja hacer muchas cosas, unas muy buenas y otras muy malas, se supone que programador es lo suficientemente "mayor" para saber que debe y que no debe hacer en un momento dado.  Efectivamente es posible hacer lo que deseas de varias formas, por ejemplo:

- Nada te impide crear un módulo donde definir las funciones (como meras funciones, no como métodos de instancia) o englobarlas en una clase y delegar en ellas. Algo similar  es lo que estás intentando, pero tienes dos errores:

  - Debes pesar la instancia a la función como argumento para que pueda acceder al atributo ya que al no ser un método de instancia no recibe ésta como primer argumento (`self`) de forma automática.
  - Además no es `self.self.texto` sino `self.texto`en todo caso, genéricamente es `instancia.texto`.

  ---

  ```
  # main.py

  from accion import evento

  def iniciar(self, event):
      evento(self)
      event.Skip()
  ```

  ---

  ```
  # accion.py

  def evento(inst):
      texto = inst.texto.GetLineText(0)
      print(texto)
  ```
- Otra opción es crear una clase que contenga los métodos y derivar de ella, lo que se conoce como ***mixing***:

  ```
  # main.py

  import wx
  import wx.xrc
  from accion import MyFrameMixin

  class MyFrame(wx.Frame, MyFrameMixin):
      def __init__(self, parent):
          wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, title=u"Muestra", pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.Size(500, 300),
                            style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

          self.SetSizeHints(wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize)

          bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

          self.texto = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
          bSizer1.Add(self.texto, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, 5)

          self.buton = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"ejecutar", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
          bSizer1.Add(self.buton, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, 5)

          self.SetSizer(bSizer1)
          self.Layout()

          self.Centre(wx.BOTH)

          # Connect Events
          self.buton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.iniciar)

      def __del__(self):
          pass

      # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
      def iniciar(self, event):
          self.evento()
          event.Skip()


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      app = wx.App(False)
      frame = MyFrame(None)
      frame.Show()
      app.MainLoop()
  ```

  ---

  ```
  # accion.py

  class MyFrameMixin:

      def evento(self):
          texto = self.texto.GetLineText(0)
          print(texto)
  ```

No obstante, debes plantearte si estas opciones son las más apropiadas, legibles y sencillas de mantener. El mixin es un recurso muy bueno y totalmente apropiado cuando se quiere extender la funcionalidad de una clase, en este caso no es que la clase `MyFrameMixin` añada funcionalidad a `MyFrame`, directamente `MyFrame` no funciona sin ella...

Si lo que quieres es eliminar código de tu main.py puedes simplemente llevar tu clase `MyFrame` a otro módulo y en el módulo principal o dónde sea importar la clase e instanciar o heredar de ella si deseamos extender su funcionalidad.

Comment: Ohhh, genial, muchas gracias por tu respuesta y otra duda, si quiero en 
 ---- accion.py ----- importar todos los modulos del --- main.py ---, esto seria con el fin de crear más botones u otro objeto, nuevamente muchas gracias